# Overload operator + for vector: namespace std

Tags: c++, vector, std

I am trying to overload the operator + and += for std::vector, and what I do is

```
namespace std {
    template<class T>
    vector<T> operator+(vector<T> x, vector<T> y) {
        vector<T> result;
        result.reserve(x.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
            result[i] = x[i] + y[i];
        return result;
   }
}
```

But I assume this is bad practice, because clang-tidy warns me "Modification of std namespace can result in undefined behavior". Is there other better practice in overloading operator for STL classes?

Comment: Just don't put the overload in the `std` namespace?

Comment: First of all, you want `vector<T>&`, not `vector<T>`

Comment: With a very few  exceptions, you are not allowed to place definitions in the std namespace, and it's not clear why you think you need to do this in this case.

Comment: You can find the answer in this part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123699/c-multiple-operator-overloads-for-the-same-operator

Comment: Find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123699/c-multiple-operator-overloads-for-the-same-operator

Comment: @FarukHossainMilon Not so.

Answer (score 6):

Best practice is not to do it.

But if you really want to you still can: just don't put it in namespace `std`.

And don't take your arguments by value, unless you're deliberately doing so in order to make the most of move semantics (which you're not).

Comment: It is reasonable to take one of them by value.

Comment: @Evgeny Not _that_ reasonable, because you'll probably want to return it, but it wouldn't be a candidate for NRVO.

Comment: Overloading operators not in the namespace of the type is usually a bad idea.  It really doesn't work very well.  And, you should definitely take the first argument by value with a cheap-to-move type like `std::vector`; it makes `a+b+c+d` really efficient.  Not the second.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, very good remark on `a+b+c+d`. Corrected my answer.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah, to be fair.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest:

1. Don't overload the operators. Create regular functions instead.
2. Put the functions in a `namespace` specific to your app.

Example:

```
namespace MyApp
{
   template <typename T>
   std::vector add(std::vector<T> const& lhs, std::vector<T> const& rhs) { ... }

   template <typename T>
   std::vector& append(std::vector<T>& lhs, std::vector<T> const& rhs) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inserting functions into `std` makes your program ill formed, no diagnostic required.

In certain limited circumstances you may insert specializations into `std`, but that cannot do what you want here.

So you cannot insert `vec + vec` into `std`.

Putting an operator in a different namespace is legal, but ill-advised.  Operators do not work well when they cannot be found via ADL/Koenig lookup.  Code that is seemingly reasonable, like `std::accumulate( vec_of_vec.begin(), vec_of_vec.end(), std::vector<int>{} )` fails to compile, among other issues.

The short answer is, `vector` isn't your type.  Don't do this.

You can create helper functions elsewhere, like `util::elementwise_add( vec, vec )`.

The `std` did not implement `+` because both concatination and elementwise operations where reasonable.  `valarray` does implement elementwise operations; possibly what you want is `std::valarray<int>` instead of `std::vector<int>`.

Failing all of this, you could write a named operator `vec +by_elem+ vec` or inherit from `std::vector` in your own namespace, use that type, and overload `+` for your type.  (Inheriting from `std::vector` is pretty safe; so long as nobody plays with heap allocated raw pointers to `std::vector`s or similar)

Comment: Very thorough. Although named operators are evil ;)

Comment: C++14 [namespace.std] says it's UB, not ill-formed-NDR, though this may have changed since

Answer (score 2):

Whether you implement addition as `operator+(...)` or as a function `add(...)`, you'd better do it this way:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> operator+(std::vector<T> x, const std::vector<T>& y) {
    assert(x.size() == y.size());
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        x[i] += y[i];
    return x;
}
```

By taking the first vector by value (and not by const-ref) you'll force a compiler to make a copy for you automatically to hold the result.

**Addition** after reading [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103950/overload-operator-for-vector-namespace-std#comment91160227_52104006).

Due to left-to-right associativity of `+`, an expression like `a + b + c` is parsed as `(a + b) + c`. Hence, if the first (and not the second) argument in `operator+(... x, ... y)` is taken by value, the *prvalue* returned by `a + b` can be moved into `x`. Otherwise, unnecessary copies will be made.

Comment: Note that `x` is not subject to NRVO, which is not good. On the other hand, it can be moved, and vector is cheaply movable, so it isn't too bad either.

Comment: @juanchopanza I disagree with "not good".  In this case, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is worth knowing about this for not all types are cheaply movable.

Answer (score 0):

You may should create your own vector class inherits from std::vector and define the new operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class MyVec : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    MyVec& operator+=(const T& add)
    {
        reserve(1);
        push_back(add);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyVec<int> vec;
    vec += 5;
    vec += 10;

    for (auto& e : vec)
    {
        std::cout << e << "\t";
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Edit**: sry i did not know that this solution causes undefined behaviour. Then i would suggest a similar solution shown in the post above. But why do you need the plus operator? Isnt push_back good enough? You could implement a reference return value to continue the addition. So you can do things like that:

```
vec + 20 + 30;
```

to add two elements (20 and 30). This is less code but is is more readable?

Comment: Not advised. The standard does not allow you to create sub-classes of `std::vector`.

Comment: ok, i did not know that. So it compiles but its undefined behaviour?

Comment: ok, thank you, i have learned smth. Just wanted to help, ill leave it to the pros :)

Comment: @RSahu how does the standard not allow it? It sounds pretty strange.

Comment: @juanchopanza If memory serves me right, the standard forbids creating sub-classes of the container classes. Is my memory failing me?

Comment: @RSahu Nothing in the answer above has undefined behavior, it's just bad practice. If someone did `std::vector<int>* p = new MyVec<int>(); delete p;` that has undefined behavior because `vector` doesn't have a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, I think it is failing you!

Comment: @Praetorian Sure, but what kind of programmer creates a dumb pointer to a vector?