# operator& that returns an int and operates on 2 vectors?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to define an `&` operator between two `std::vector<int>`. This operator should bit-wise and each element of both vectors together and return the number of non-zero components of the resulting vector.

However, if I define `int operator&(const std::vector<int> &lhs, const std::vector<int> &rhs)`, it the compiler doesn't like it and requires `operator&` to return a boolean. Is this actually a restriction with `operator&`?

Comment: Is [this code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YkmXjJ2YMP/) what you want? If so, I succeeded in compiling and running it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A: Overload operator + for vector: namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104645)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to define an & operator between two `std::vector<int>`.

You may not (at least not globally; it can in theory be done in a custom namespace but I recommend against it). Operator overloads for standard templates with no user defined type arguments are reserved to the standard library.

I recommend writing a regular function instead.

> Any idea why there's that restriction?

Because this restriction allows the standard library to change and add any operator overload that the committee wishes without breaking previously well defined programs that have their own conflicting overloads (by virtue of not allowing such overloads to be defined).

---

> operator& to return a boolean. Is this actually a restriction with operator&?

No. This is actually not a restriction of binary operator&. It may return `int`.

Comment: Any idea why there's that restriction?