Why `std::plus` cannot call `operator+` for `std::vector`?
Both GCC and MSVC cannot compile.
GCC complains: invalid operands to binary expression ('typename std::remove_reference<vector<int> &>::type' (aka 'std::vector<int>') and 'std::vector<int>').
However, they can both compile if I explicitly write a + b in a lambda.
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

vector<int> operator+(const vector<int> &a, const vector<int> &b) {
    vector<int> c;
    transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), back_inserter(c), plus());
    return c;
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> vv{{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
    // vector<int> s = accumulate(vv.begin() + 1, vv.end(), vv[0]); // Error
    vector<int> s = accumulate(vv.begin() + 1, vv.end(), vv[0], [](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return a + b; });
    return 0;
}


https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

It can compile if the operator+ is surrounded by namespace std { }.

@chaosink That will be undefined behavior. You should not add overloads to standard namespace. Undefined behavior means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The progra may just crash.

Operators should always be in namespaces where ADL can find them, otherwise they don't work reliably. This means that it's not possible to add operator overloads for std::vector<int>, since they'd have to be in namespace std. And in general, you're not supposed to add operators to the types you don't own.

What HolyBlackCat says. Though there is no problem with providing an operator+ for your custom struct my_adding_vector { std::vector<int> value; };.

Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104645/580083
